# Nested loop not triggering

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

Goal is to make a quiz that repeats on false answers, however must also continue to the next question when the user inputs "skip"

As it stands, my nested loop intended to act as the "skip" break condition but is not triggering.
The program proceeds as expected when the answer is correct, but loops even when meeting the 'break' condition.

```
print(" please answer in the form of a number ( 1, 15 , 7 etc. )")
answer1 = (input(" what is the square root of four  \n")).lower
skip = "skip"
while answer1 != "2":
    if answer1 != skip:
        print("incorrect please try again \n")
        answer1 = (input(" what is the square root of four  \n"))
    elif answer1 == "skip":
        break
else:
    print("correct \n")
```

Comment: Your `else` block is invalid. Or maybe you forgot to indent it correctly.

Comment: @bichanna: The `else` is perfectly legal.  Probably not what they intended, but actually legal.  It runs when the `while` statement exits because of a false condition rather than a break.

Comment: Oh, really! Thanks. Learned a new thing!

Comment: The bug is that `.lower` should be `.lower()`.  as written `answer1`s value is a function rather than a string.  And my apologies to the OP.  The `else:` is precisely what they were trying to do!!

Comment: @bichanna: This usage is extremely rare, so it's not surprising you hadn't seen it.  I've used it only a couple of times in years of writing Python. You can also use it with `for` loops.